# What's the data format of Athena's .csv.metadata files?

Tags: hive, amazon-athena, file-format

What's the data format of the `.csv.metadata` files written by Amazon Athena?

Alongside the output file of every query there is a metadata file. It looks like it describes the schema of the result. I assume this is what Athena uses to create the `ResultSet.ResultSetMetadata` part of the response of `GetQueryResults` requests, and that it is somehow created by Hive or Presto.

```
2019-04-23 14:51:29         27 e7629796-9b91-476a-bfb7-2fe6c9595bce.csv
2019-04-23 14:51:29         56 e7629796-9b91-476a-bfb7-2fe6c9595bce.csv.metadata
2019-04-27 14:23:53    1591958 ebe432ac-db7b-4ea1-b5de-529350d1a02a.csv
2019-04-27 14:23:53        712 ebe432ac-db7b-4ea1-b5de-529350d1a02a.csv.metadata
2019-04-25 16:31:23      10152 eeb6f4ab-9ac3-4a7e-81c4-0cc155187acb.csv
2019-04-25 16:31:23        494 eeb6f4ab-9ac3-4a7e-81c4-0cc155187acb.csv.metadata
2019-04-25 22:30:56   22384376 f0160ff7-e5b3-466d-926a-a660a5208c5f.csv
2019-04-25 22:30:56        494 f0160ff7-e5b3-466d-926a-a660a5208c5f.csv.metadata
```

Here's a hexdump of `e7629796-9b91-476a-bfb7-2fe6c9595bce.csv.metadata` from the listing above:

```
00000000  0a 1b 32 30 31 39 30 34  32 33 5f 31 32 35 31 32  |..20190423_12512|
00000010  38 5f 30 30 30 30 31 5f  65 68 74 75 72 22 19 0a  |8_00001_ehtur"..|
00000020  04 68 69 76 65 22 03 61  72 79 2a 03 61 72 79 32  |.hive".ary*.ary2|
00000030  05 61 72 72 61 79 48 03                           |.arrayH.|
```

It's `ResultSet.ResultSetMetadata` looks like this:

```
"ResultSetMetadata": {
  "ColumnInfo": [
    {
      "CatalogName": "hive",
      "SchemaName": "",
      "TableName": "",
      "Name": "ary",
      "Label": "ary",
      "Type": "array",
      "Precision": 0,
      "Scale": 0,
      "Nullable": "UNKNOWN",
      "CaseSensitive": false
    }
  ]
}
```

I realise that these are internal file to Athena, but I'm curious.

Comment: I have reverse engineered the format, here's a parser: https://gist.github.com/iconara/4969c247e8abb69600cdbe6f4b20f50b – however, I would still like to know if there is a real answer to this question, and if the assumptions I've made in my parser are correct.

Comment: Some more research indicates that the format is in fact a Protocol Buffers.

Comment: Seems to be a protobuf encoded version of presto-jdbc/src/main/java/com/facebook/presto/jdbc/PrestoResultSetMetaData.java and presto-jdbc/src/main/java/com/facebook/presto/jdbc/ColumnInfo.java

Answer (score -3):

Metadata files are not human readable (binary format) and are meant for Athena.

From AWS documentation:

> DML and DDL query metadata files are saved in binary format and are
> not human readable. The file extension corresponds to the related
> query results file. Athena uses the metadata when reading query
> results using the GetQueryResults action. **Although these files can be
> deleted, we do not recommend it because important information about
> the query is lost.**

For more details look into "***Identifying query output files***" section in : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying.htmlIdentifying

Comment: > I realise that these are internal file to Athena, but I'm curious.

Comment: Curious of what? Why it's in binary form! Or why Athena uses an internal file to manage file schema?