# I wonder this log in s3 bucket ( I use athena)

Tags: amazon-athena

I use AWS Athena. 
My bucket which uses Athena saving something logs like this:

```
~~.txt
~~.txt.metadata
~~.csv
~~.csv.metadata
```

My bucket path is `s3://bucket/mybucket(folder?)/`

I don't know what this log. I don't want to save this log in my bucket. Let me know what this log is it and how to don't save this logs.

This log might not be query result log. because result log saving at the other bucket.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55991018/whats-the-data-format-of-athenas-csv-metadata-files

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen Thank you. so this log is resultSet? What should I do for don't save this log? I don't speak English well. Please Understand me.

Comment: Actually I don't know what is in these files. I just know this question was already asked.

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen Oh. I see. Thank you!