# AWS Athena too slow for an api?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

The plan was to get data from aws data exchange, move it to an s3 bucket then query it by aws athena for a data api. Everything works, just feels a bit slow.

No matter the dataset nor the query I can't get below 2 second in athena response time. Which is a lot for an API. I checked the best practices but seems that those are also above 2 sec.

So my question:
Is 2 sec the minimal response time for athena?

If so then I have to switch to postgres.

Comment: We use athena to query some access logs, custom logs to debug some applications. I am not sure whether it is good for a production endpoint. As documentation stated; `query services like Amazon Athena make it easy to run interactive queries against data directly in Amazon S3 without worrying about formatting data or managing infrastructure. For example, Athena is great if you just need to run a quick query on some web logs to troubleshoot a performance issue on your site.`

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/athena/faqs/#When_to_use_Athena_vs_other_big_data_services you may check here.

Comment: Amazon Athena is amazing for its ability to look through large quantities of data without loading it into a database. However, if you are seeking fast response times, then you will want to **use a database**, rather than a query engine.

Comment: Don't see it mentioned anywhere but the concurrent execution limit for Athena is fairly low. The soft-limit starts at 25 concurrent queries but is increaseable. On top of that, StartExecution has a soft limit of 20 r/s with burst up to 80 r/s (so you'd likely run into issues trying to start queries if you're servicing over 20 requests/sec that included Athena queries)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Athena is indeed not a low latency data store. You will very rarely see response times below one second, and often they will be considerably longer. In the general case Athena is not suitable as a backend for an API, but of course that depends on what kind of an API it is. If it's some kind of analytics service, perhaps users don't expect sub second response times? I have built APIs that use Athena that work really well, but those were services where response times in seconds were expected (and even considered fast), and I got help from the Athena team to tune our account to our workload.

To understand why Athena is "slow", we can dissect what happens when you submit a query to Athena:

1. Your code starts a query by using the `StartQueryExecution` API call
2. The Athena service receives the query, and puts it on a queue. If you're unlucky your query will sit in the queue for a while
3. When there is available capacity the Athena service takes your query from the queue and makes a query plan
4. The query plan requires loading table metadata from the Glue catalog, including the list of partitions, for all tables included in the query
5. Athena also lists all the locations on S3 it got from the tables and partitions to produce a full list of files that will be processed
6. The plan is then executed in parallel, and depending on its complexity, in multiple steps
7. The results of the parallel executions are combined and a result is serialized as CSV and written to S3
8. Meanwhile your code checks if the query has completed using the `GetQueryExecution` API call, until it gets a response that says that the execution has succeeded, failed, or been cancelled
9. If the execution succeeded your code uses the `GetQueryResults` API call to retrieve the first page of results
10. To respond to that API call, Athena reads the result CSV from S3, deserializes it, and serializes it as JSON for the API response
11. If there are more than 1000 rows the last steps will be repeated

A Presto expert could probably give more detail about steps 4-6, even though they are probably a bit modified in Athena's version of Presto. The details aren't very important for this discussion though.

If you run a query over a lot of data, tens of gigabytes or more, the total execution time will be dominated by step 6. If the result is also big, 7 will be a factor.

If your data set is small, and/or involves thousands of files on S3, then 4-5 will instead dominate.

Here are some reasons why Athena queries can never be fast, even if they wouldn't touch S3 (for example `SELECT NOW()`):

- There will at least be three API calls before you get the response, a `StartQueryExecution`, a `GetQueryExecution`, and a `GetQueryResults`, just their round trip time (RTT) would add up to more than 100ms.
- You will most likely have to call `GetQueryExecution` multiple times, and the delay between calls will puts a bound on how quickly you can discover that the query has succeeded, e.g. if you call it every 100ms you will on average add half of 100ms + RTT to the total time because on average you'll miss the actual completion time by this much.
- Athena will writes the results to S3 before it marks the execution as succeeded, and since it produces a single CSV file this is not done in parallel. A big response takes time to write.
- The `GetQueryResults` must read the CSV from S3, parse it and serialize it as JSON. Subsequent pages must skip ahead in the CSV, and may be even slower.
- Athena is a multi tenant service, all customers are competing for resources, and your queries will get queued when there aren't enough resources available.

If you want to know what affects the performance of your queries you can use the `ListQueryExecutions` API call to list recent query execution IDs (I think you can go back 90 days at the most), and then use `GetQueryExecution` to get query statistics (see [the documentation for `QueryExecution.Statistics`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/APIReference/API_QueryExecutionStatistics.html) for what each property means). With this information you can figure out if your slow queries are because of queueing, execution, or the overhead of making the API calls (if it's not the first two, it's likely the last).

There are some things you can do to cut some of the delays, but these tips are unlikely to get you down to sub second latencies:

- If you query a lot of data use file formats that are optimized for that kind of thing, Parquet is almost always the answer – and also make sure your file sizes are optimal, around 100 MB.
- Avoid lots of files, and avoid deep hierarchies. Ideally have just one or a few files per partition, and don't organize files in "subdirectories" (S3 prefixes with slashes) except for those corresponding to partitions.
- Avoid running queries at the top of the hour, this is when everyone else's scheduled jobs run, there's significant contention for resources the first minutes of every hour.
- Skip `GetQueryExecution`, download the CSV from S3 directly. The `GetQueryExecution` call is convenient if you want to know the data types of the columns, but if you already know, or don't care, reading the data directly can save you some precious tens of milliseconds. If you need the column data types you can get the `….csv.metadata` file that is written alongside the result CSV, it's undocumented Protobuf data, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55991018/whats-the-data-format-of-athenas-csv-metadata-files) and [here](https://github.com/burtcorp/athena-jdbc/blob/master/src/main/java/io/burt/athena/result/AthenaMetaDataParser.java) for more information.
- Ask the Athena service team to tune your account. This might not be something you can get without higher tiers of support, I don't really know the politics of this and you need to start by talking to your account manager.

Comment: great response. We ingest data from external sources to S3 for real-time lookups in Lambda, and the latency is 2-3 sec, sometimes close to 10 sec. I wonder if a solution would be to use use Presto (or similar) in Lambda directly against S3, avoiding Athena altogether. AWS S3 Select could help too I guess. But we will need to find the right CSV / JSON segment in S3, so I guess need DynamoDB for this or some index in EFS. Are you aware of solutions that were cooked in this area?

Comment: I don't think any general query engine that runs on data on S3 will give you consistent subsecond latencies – you will need something bespoke for that. I've seen analytics engines built with Lambda and S3, but they've all been for the ~5s target rather than ~1s. It depends a lot on a lot of things, unfortunately. If you want to discuss it in more detail you can find me on the Open Guide to AWS Slack, or the AWS Developers Slack.